# How do I change color of cell which have greater than zero value in datagrid

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

`enter code here`

i have two cell in grid i want to chage one cell color and value by zero when i entered in other cell greater then zero value

```
    private void grdDetail_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
        { 
            if (this.IsLoadComplete) 
              { 
                UpdateValueofQtyCell(e.ColumnIndex); 
              } 
       }
  private void UpdateValueofQtyCell(int index)
        {
            int cur_row = grdDetail.CurrentRow.Index;

            if (index == 1)
            {
                grdDetail[1, cur_row].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
                grdDetail[2, cur_row].Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(224, 224, 224);
                grdDetail[2, cur_row].Value = 0;
            }
           else  if (index == 1)
            {
                grdDetail[2, cur_row].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
                grdDetail[1 cur_row].Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(224, 224, 224);
                grdDetail[1, cur_row].Value = 0;
             }
        }
```

Comment: So what did you try so far that did not work?

Comment: private void grdDetail_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.IsLoadComplete)
            {
                UpdateValueofQtyCell(e.ColumnIndex);
            }
        }

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; i++)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() != "0")
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually i have Done the code that is given above but problem is this  when i put last saved values than grid cell color is not coming

Answer (score 0):

create below variable at class level.

```
bool IsAnyGreaterThanZero = false;
```

then call first below function which tell if any cell value is greater than zero.

```
private void CheckForGreaterThanZero()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; i++)
      {

         if ((int)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value > 0)
            {
              IsAnyGreaterThanZero = true;
            }
      }
}
```

then call below function to change color of those cells which has value equal to zero.

```
private void ChangeOtherCellColor()
 {
  if(IsAnyGreaterThanZero)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; i++)
      {
        if ((int)intdataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value == 0)
        {
            DataGridViewCellStyle CellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
            CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Style = CellStyle;
        }
      }
   }


  }
```

Comment: you can put it in : void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e){.........}

Comment: if one cell have greater than zero value than i want change the other cell color which have zero value

Comment: @minu You can try the event void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)

Comment: i do ur code mr Wajid Ali but when load with last value cell color is not coming

Comment: how i can get one page gridview value on other page win application